# pasar un objeto al controlador de C# mediante AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, mvc

necesito mandar un varias características mediante AJAX hacia un controlador , pero al ejecutar el AJAX y depurar en el controlador este no recibe la información del ajax , recibe dicha  crea los objetos de las clases (lo que entiendo significa si esta entrando el ajax) pero los crea vacíos

```
public class filtrosData 
    {
        public int TipoOperacion { get; set; }
        public string? Buscar { get; set; } 
        public int? tipoPropiedad { get; set; }
        public int? tipoMoneda { get; set; }
        public int? precioMin { get; set; }
        public int? precioMax { get; set; }
        public int? tipoSuperficie { get; set; }
        public int? tipoMedida { get; set; }
        public int? superficieMin { get; set;}
        public int? superficieMax { get; set;}
        public List<int?> caracteristicasF { get;set; } 

    }
```

y este controlador

```
        public ActionResult BusquedaFiltros( filtrosData filtros, [FromBody] caracteristicasF caracteristicas, Usuario usuario)
            {
            var PropiedadesEcomerce = new ListaPropiedadesEcomerce();

            // Crear una lista de objetos caracteristicas
          

            var Filtros = _EcommerceData.FiltrosEcomerce(caracteristicasList);


            return View(PropiedadesEcomerce);
        }
```

```
    filtros = { TipoOperacion, Buscar, tipoPropiedad, tipoMoneda, precioMin, precioMax, tipoSuperficie, tipoMedida, superficieMin, superficieMax}
        var caracteristicas = {
            caracteristicas: { 1: 2, 2: null, 3: null }
        }

        var usuario = {
            Nombre: "John",
            Edad: 25,
            Email: "john@example.com"
        };

        var url = "/Ecommerce/BusquedaFiltros" ;
        var url = "/Ecommerce/BusquedaFiltros" ;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            filtros: filtros,
            usuario: JSON.stringify(usuario),
        },
        contentType: 'application/json', // Especifica el tipo de contenido como JSON

            resolve(listaID, busqueda);

        },
        
    });
```

pero al ejecutar el codigo AJAX  cuando entra al controlador en el parametro de usuario  llena el objeto como Edad =0 , Nombre = null, Email =null en lugar de los parametros que le estoy mandando

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos**

En lugar de:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        filtros: filtros,
        usuario: JSON.stringify(usuario),
    },
    contentType: 'application/json', // Especifica el tipo de contenido como JSON

    resolve(listaID, busqueda);

    },

});
```

Prueba de la siguiente forma (básicamente es todo el `data` con `JSON.stringify` y no solo a `usuario`):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        filtros: filtros,
        usuario: usuario,
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json', // Especifica el tipo de contenido como JSON

    resolve(listaID, busqueda);

    },

});
```

Comment: hola Roberto , intente con eso pero en lugar de traer usuarios vacio me llena ambos objetos como vacio

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes decorar la acción BusquedaFiltros como método HttpPost, segundo, no debes retornar un ActionResult, debes retornar un Json. Intenta con el siguiente código

```
//***Decora tu acción con el atributo HttpPost para indicar que usarás ese método
//de igual forma vas a retornar un Json no un View
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult BusquedaFiltros( filtrosData filtros, [FromBody] caracteristicasF caracteristicas, Usuario usuario)
{
            var PropiedadesEcomerce = new ListaPropiedadesEcomerce();

            // Crear una lista de objetos caracteristicas
          

            var Filtros = _EcommerceData.FiltrosEcomerce(caracteristicasList);


            return Json(PropiedadesEcomerce); //***Aqui conviertes tu objeto a Json
}
```